# Text field sorting in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j order by command to sort the textual data. In this process, all the data is sorted as per alphabetical order, but all the data starting with capital letters is sorted separately and data starting with small letters sorted separately. Following is an example:

```
Input: ["A","C","B","b","c","a"]
Output: ["A", "B", "C", "a", "b", "c"]
```

I am using following cypher query:

```
WITH ["A","C","B","b","c","a"] AS list 
UNWIND list AS item 
RETURN item 
ORDER BY item ASC
```

How can I get result: ["a", "A", "b", "B", "c", "C"] ?

Thanks,
Vishal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the order by clause you could use the `toLower` or `toUpper` function to sort on lowercase or uppercase values first and then sort on the actual value as a secondary sort parameter.

```
WITH ["A","C","B","b","c","a"] AS list 
UNWIND list AS item 
RETURN item 
ORDER by toLower(item) ASC, item DESC
```